# Kitematic will not allow mysql container to use local storage

Tags: docker, kitematic

**** SOLVED THIS - ANSWER BELOW - IT MAY HELP OTHERS ****

Latest version of docker. MYSQL 5.7.22 container. Running on Mac OS X.

[image]

It runs fine, but whenever I define local folder (see red arrow) I will get this Kitematic error and the entire thing halts:

```
Initializing database
mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/var/lib/mysql/is_writable' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2018-07-02T16:43:02.733450Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2018-07-02T16:43:02.737046Z 0 [ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory exists and is not writable. Aborting.
2018-07-02T16:43:02.737336Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I was told the solution is to add a "user" to the docker-compose.yml, but I don't have one on my disk, anywhere I can see. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that I had VirtualBox installed prior to installing dockers/Kitematic, and for some reason Docker was setting itself up to use this. Once I removed this configuration item and allowed dockers to go "Native" this issue was resolved.